# Create a leader board from score entries

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
[{
    score: 7000,
    mapId: 1,
    profileId: 12
}, {
    score: 400,
    mapId: 1,
    profileId: 6
}, {
    score: 12000,
    mapId: 1,
    profileId: 12
}, {
    score: 5000,
    mapId: 1,
    profileId: 12
}, {
    score: 120,
    mapId: 1,
    profileId: 8
}]
```

I have a game's REST API and users send their map scores to a route and I save them in Mongo, users can have multiple score entries for multiple mapIds or for one mapId.

JSON above is a result of all documents, with score, mapId and profileId. You can see a profileId can have multiple scores for a mapId, I'm asking the best query for getting the top 3 best scores, but there cant be scores from multiple profileIds, which means it must be a profile's highest score only. The result should look like this:

```
[{
    score: 12000,
    mapId: 1,
    profileId: 12
}, {
    score: 400,
    mapId: 1,
    profileId: 6
}, {
    score: 120,
    mapId: 1,
    profileId: 8
}]
```

I have tried following aggregation to get `mapId: 1` leaderboard but scores can get mixed up and the lowest score weirdly sometimes turns into the highest score.

```
this.db.aggregate([
     { $match: { mapId: 1 } },
     { $group: { _id: "$profileId", score: { $max: "$score" }, root: { $first: "$$ROOT" } } },
     { $sort: { score: -1 } },
     { $limit: 3 }
]);
```

I'm looking for something that does it all easy without anything extra or dumb.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cf4gIG9v5zL) what you are looking for?

Comment: @ray notice that the sort inside the setWindowFields is applied separately to each grouping, so the final results are out of order.  Probably need 1 more sort stage to fix that.

Comment: @Joe That's a good point. I have a doubt about my approach too as it doesn't seem much shorter/cleaner than OP's approach

Comment: The correct answer (in my opinion) for the general case is ray's answer with a `sort` in the end (as @Joe stated). It is better than the OP's answer and @Fourchette's answer in case there are other fields in the document. @ray, please post it as the answer and I'll vote for it

Answer (score 0):

To be honest your query is already good enough i think. You should remove the `root : {$first :"$$ROOT"}` because the `$first` operator won't always give  you the doc with the highest score.

```
this.db.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      mapId: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$profileId",
      score: {
        $max: "$score"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      score: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 3
  },
  {
    $set: {
      profileId: "$_id",
      mapId: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "_id"
  }
])
```

You should add some `$set` and `$unset` stage for your results to match the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$setWindowFields` to compute `$rank` for each profileId. You can then take `rank: 1` to get the top score for each player. Finally, do a `$sort` + `$limit` to get the top 3 scores.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      mapId: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": "$profileId",
      "sortBy": {
        "score": -1
      },
      "output": {
        "rank": {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      rank: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "rank"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      score: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 3
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L3_bGESJe2K)

Thanks @Joe and @nimrod serok for the constructive feedbacks.